# How do I evaluate the accuracy of sport trade probabilities?

Tags: probability

Recently, a sports broadcaster gave probabilities of certain trades occurring before the 2015 NHL trade deadline:

[image: Likelihood of Maple Leafs being traded before the trade deadline, according to TSN]

I've seen unsubstantiated sports claims before, but this one struck me as interesting due to the granularity of the estimates (rather than just saying likely/unlikely).

After the trade deadline, each of these events will have occurred, or not occurred.  How would a statistician evaluate the quality of the estimates (in hindsight)?

For example, I know that I could take all of the "30%" estimates, and over an infinite sample, if they were accurate, it should converge on 30% of the events occurring.  But I don't know:

1. How to reconcile this with a variety of probabilities.
2. How to put a number on the "quality" of the probabilities (I'm assuming this will be paired with some confidence metric).

To extract the data from the image, here is what we're working with:

```
P(CF) = 0.85
P(DW) = 0.85
P(KH) = 0.75
P(TB) = 0.6
P(JL) = 0.6
P(MS) = 0.6
P(JG) = 0.3
P(JR) = 0.3
P(NK) = 0.3
P(DP) = 0.2
P(PK) = 0.2
```

Comment: For flavor, this was found on an [/r/leafs post](http://www.reddit.com/r/leafs/comments/2uowmz/tsn_insider_trading_chances_of_leaf_players_being/).

Answer (score 1):

Under the hypothesis that the probabilities are correct, the total number of correct predictions will follow a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). It's not a nice function to work with, but we can get a rough approximation using the mean and variance, which we can calculate:

- The expected number of successes is just the sum of the probabilities: $5.55$
- The variance is just the sum of $p_i(1-p_i)$: $2.11$

We can try to approximate this by a normal distribution, in which case, we would conclude that there are errors in the predictions with $95\%$ confidence if the number of successes, S, falls outside the following interval:

$$5.55\pm1.96\sqrt{2.11}$$

Roughly speaking, it would be highly unlikely for us to see greater than $9$ or less than $3$ successful predictions, assuming that the prediction probabilities were accurate.

**Quality of Predictions**

I'd like to suggest two different measures for accuracy, then combine them:

Lets take the example where we give every prediction $i$ is expected to have a $\rho_i$ chance of success. The weakest prediction one can make is to assign $p_i=\rho_i$, since it is perfectly along expectations. Conversely, predicting something completely opposite to expectations is a very strong prediction. So, a metric for the strength $S$ of each prediction can be:

$$S_i=\frac{1}{\max\{\rho_i,1-\rho_i\}}|p_i-\rho_i|$$

Overall strength of a group of predictions can be summarized by the mean strength:

$$\bar S:= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N S_i $$

Ok, so that takes care of the strength of the predictions, now for the accuracy. Again, Ill start with a single prediction. Lets call our metric the Deviation ($D$) given the observed outcome $O_i$ (i.e., success or failure):

$$D_i:=|O_i-p_i|$$

And, similarly to the strength assessment, we can use the mean deviation as our aggregate metric:

$$\bar{D}:=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N D_i $$

Now, we have a two-dimensional assessment of the prediction: its "strength" or *a priori* confidence, and its relative accuracy.

In the case of $50\%$ prediction across the board, the mean deviation will be $0.5$ but the mean strength will be $0$. Moderately wrong, but useless predictions.

In the case where each prediction is $0\%$ or $100\%$, the strength would be $1$ and the mean deviation could be anywhere from $0$ to $1$, depending on how well they did. So, if they are spot on, you would have very strong, very accurate predictions, or if they are way off you would have very strong, but very wrong predictions.

Combining these two, we can create a strength adjusted accuracy $A$:

$$A:=\bar S\times (1-\bar{D})$$

This measure combines the two ideas, favoring predictions that are both strong and accurate, and discouraging overly conservative or overly radical predictions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this gives me a lot to chew on.  One thing to help me parse all this: what do we mean by "correct prediction/success" in this context?  If you roll a 6-sided die, and say that 3 has a 1/6 probability of occurring, but it doesn't, would you consider that a success or not a success?

Comment: @MarkPeters Success means that the predicted event occurred. So, in your dice example, you would have a failure.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So the first part of the answer is kind of just a quick metric...if the actually number of trades wildly diverges from 5-6, there's something wrong with the numbers.  But even if there are 5-6, that's no indication that the individual estimates were on point (because they could have been completely off-base about *which* trades would occur).

Comment: @MarkPeters Sorry...yes, I included a basic omnibus hypothesis test to see if its plausible that the predictions are all correct. I then switched gears and described a way to measure the quality of the predictions. They are two different things, but i don't think I made that clear.

Comment: I'm just running through some thoughts in my head, and trying to get around the concept of strength.  Say I wanted to estimate the probability of heads/tails in 10 consecutive coin flips.  We know the probability of each being heads to be 0.5.  But according to this metric, saying `P(1) = 0.5, P(2) =0.5`... is a set of useless predictions, because A = 0?

Comment: @MarkPeters you are correct. In that situation, predictions are useless. However, you could still assess if you were correct using the hypothesis test I outlined. Again, I have two different things: one is a test of correctness of the probabilities, the other is an evaluation of their quality or usefulness.

Comment: @MarkPeters also, if one wanted to increase the strength of their predictions by assigning $P(i)=1$, then the strength would go up, but the deviation would, on average, be $0.5$ so you'd be a mediocre predictor. It could be the case that you would get none of them correct, so you could get as low as a zero.

Comment: @MarkPeters although, this metric does justify, on average, stronger predictions over more accurate ones...

Comment: I really like the idea of pairing deviation with strength, I'm just having trouble with the idea that 50% is not a strong prediction.  It seems to depend on what you're looking at.  For example, if I say there's a 50% chance that Mary, Joe, and Steve will each get hit by lightning in the next 3 days, that seems like an incredibly strong prediction to me, and if one of them does get hit by lightning, I'd be hailed as a psychic.  But I would have thought there'd be a way to normalize the strength without needing specific domain knowledge, or begging the question (i.e. knowing the "true" P).

Comment: @MarkPeters I think we are talking about two different things. The strength here is independent of any expectations, whereas the *interpretation* of the strength (maybe call this surprise or provocativeness) is dependent on prevailing expectations.

Comment: @MarkPeters so, saying $50\%$ chance of rain tomorrow would be quite bold in the dead of winter, but very unsurprising in the spring.

Comment: @MarkPeters but, like you pointed out that requires prior data. I guess one *could* adjust for this by letting $S_i=\frac{1}{\rho_i}|p_i-\rho_i|$ where $\rho_i$ is the "expected" or "prior" probabiltity.

Comment: I think you'd have to...if instead of 0.5, we used the historical fraction of players that are traded within the ~35 days leading up to the trade deadline.  Then if you say less or more than that number, whatever it is, it's a strong prediction.

Comment: @MarkPeters that makes sense, so I will modify my formula to make the strength score be relative to expectations.

Comment: @MarkPeters ok, so I updated the strength metric...now strength and deviation are much more independent, making their combination more useful.